# How to re-index default Mongo index?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

Well, I am fixing a MongoDB collection which has 100million records.  the previous developer overwrite the default _id  with something really wrong.   Now, when I fix it, how can I regenerate the _id index?   Other than mongoRestore, is there any faster way?

---

here is my update procedure:

1) copy database from original DB to anther DB.

2) remove the _id for all records.

3) regenerate _id for all records (That's what I'm not sure how to do )

4) Copy the collection back to origin DB with the new _id   (or the other way is make mongoDump from the new / temp DB,  Then send the file to the original DB, MongoRestore i.e (Then each record will have the new _id . That way will work but seems slower. )

Comment: why do you think you have to regenerate?

Comment: Well.. because the _id was overwritten with an imporper hash value that causing collision.  So, i need to remove the old one. and then restore one with Mongo's default way.

Comment: How are you restoring the _id values?  If you are reading each document and then updating the _id, you don't need to rebuild the index.  If you want to restore to the value in the backup, how you can do this depends on how your backup was taken.

Comment: that's what I want to know.  How to restore the _id value generated by Mongo by default. 

Here is my step. (see above)

Answer (score 1):

The default MongoDB '_id' value is generated by the MongoDB driver on the client side when the document is first inserted.  It is generated using the current time, the host name of the machine where the client is running, the process ID of the client, and a incrementing value used to distinguish multiple operations by the same process.

For details, see http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs#ObjectIDs-BSONObjectIDSpecification

As a result, there's no way for you to reconstruct the original default MongoDB '_id' value unless you happen to have stored all of the information I mentioned above as entries in your document.

In addition, the '_id' field is immutable -- it cannot be changed.  I'm not sure how the previous developer overwrote the _id field in the first place -- my best guess is that he fetched the document, changed the value of the _id field, deleted the old one, and inserted the new one.

If the contents of your documents other than the '_id' field have not changed since you did the 'mongodump', then your quickest way to get the data back would be to restore that dump file.

If the contents of your documents have changed, and you want to keep the changes, then you'll need to do the same thing the previous developer did in reverse: fetch every document in the collection, use your native driver's facilities for creating a new ObjectID, delete the old document and save the data as a new document with a new _id.